# Why DatePicker component is flipping day and month on its own?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Developing C#/WPF application with Visual Studio 2010.

I have several date pickers and when I type the day and month with keyboard instead of choosing with the calendar, the **DatePicker** component flips the day and month on its own.

We have set a custom format for the DatePicker to show only day and month but not year, although it has preset year, hidden from view.

```
StringFormat='dd/MM'
```

How can I tell this component to not flip the day and month?

Is the custom format causing this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "flip"? What is displayed, what action do you take, what happens then and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @nvoigt when you type the day and month instead of choosing with the calendar, for example "05/01" the component by itself flips the day and the month, to "01/05"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture to set the culture of the app. Probably your machine has a different culture to the one you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, we use format, day/month/year instead of month/day/year